# NodeJS - RethinkDB: Cannot read property 'id' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb

I created this project: https://codeforgeek.com/2016/03/building-real-time-polling-app-rethinkdb-nodejs/

Now I have inserted a delete function that works through POSTMAN DELETE request, it deletes the table from the db database, but the console / app crashes, I get this in the console:

[image]

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null

When I start the app again (node app.js). The question/table was deleted ! The problem is the crash.

Here is feeds.js, where it says the error is:

```
var rethinkdb = require('rethinkdb');
var db = require('./db');
var pollObject = new db();
module.exports = function(socket) {
  pollObject.connectToDb(function(err,connection) {
  if(err) {
    return callback(true,"Error connecting to database");
  }
  rethinkdb.table('poll').changes().run(connection,function(err,cursor) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    cursor.each(function(err,row) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
      if(Object.keys(row).length > 0) {
        socket.broadcast.emit("changeFeed",{"id" : row.new_val.id,"polls" : row.new_val.polls});
      }
    });
  });
  });
};
```

Comment: The very last line before the error says `{"new_val":null, `..

Comment: may i know what u get in your console? because you logged it there

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your

```
socket.broadcast.emit("changeFeed",{"id" : row.new_val.id,"polls" : row.new_val.polls});
```

is trying to fetch the ID from an object that's no longer there (i.e. deleted).

Try changing the line to say something else.